# How to get all the packages from a distribution's repo onto an offline Ubuntu machine?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I want to create an offline repository but I'm stumped in the sense I don't know how to easily get all the packages for Ubuntu's repo. On RHEL, I can easily download the Universal DVD which is like 10 GB and then mount and there you go I have an offline RHEL repository. For Ubuntu, they all require tools that assume you have connection to the internet like `apt-mirror` or `dpkg` (for scan packages). I just need the files, I know how to setup the repo. Any ideas?

See from here. Setting up a YUM repository can be done like so:

```
You can also use your installation CD as a source for repositories.

First, mount the cd, then copy the files into your FTP directory with the following:
```

Src: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/create-local-yum-repository-centos

How to do something similar in Ubuntu?

EDIT:

When looking at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository

It explains to download the Release, Release.gpg, Content_files-.gz; and then the  Packages.bz2, Packages.gz, Release files from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists but these files are hardly more than a few MBs. And then its silent on the actual 20+ GB repository. I'm stuck. None of the documentation makes sense. WHAT AM I  SUPPOSED TO DO WITH apt-medium??

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: It doesn't. Those are really old (over a decade ago). And they assume things back then. It doesn't help.

Comment: How do you download the packages?